Como puedo usar el mismo menú de mi html en otros html
Estoy trabajando con un proyecto java - spring boot y me encuentro construyendo el front end con HTML, CSS Y JAVASCRIPT e hice un menú de navegación para mi aplicación en un html individual y lo que quiero hacer es que dicho menú lo tengan los demás módulos/archivos de mi aplicación con total funcionalidad que ajuste en mi css y js sin tener que copiar y pegar todo el codigo html, css y javascript en los demás archivos html:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ECO DRIP</title>
</head>
<body>    
    <div class="menu">
        <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
        <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="barra-lateral" id="menuContent">
        <div>
            <div class="nombre-pagina">
                <ion-icon name="cloud-outline" id="cloud"></ion-icon>
                <span>Inmobiliaria J.R</span>
            </div>
    
            <button class="boton">
                <ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon>
                <span>Cerrar Sesion</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <nav class="navegacion">
            <ul class="list">
                <li class="list__item">
                    <div class="list__buttom">
                        <ion-icon name="menu-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <a href="/Inicio.html" class="nav__link">
                            <span>INICIO</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="list__item list__item--click">
                    <div class="list__buttom list__buttom--click">
                        <ion-icon name="people-outline"></ion-icon>
                        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                            <span>TERCEROS</span>
                        </a>
                        <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" class="list__arrow"></ion-icon>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="list__show">
                        <li class="list__submenu list__submenu--click">
                            <div class="list__buttom__sub list__buttom__sub--click">
                                <a href="#" class="nav__link__sub">
                                    <span>GENERAL</span>
                                </a>
                                <ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline" class="list__arrow__sub"></ion-icon>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list__show__sub">
                                <li class="list__inside__sub">
                                    <a href="/Terceros/HTML/ConsultarTerceros.html" class="nav__link nav__link--inside">Terceros Clientes</a>
                                </li>                                                                   
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>                    
            </ul>
                     
        </nav>                       
    </div>          
</body>
</html>




Omar. Para comenzar un proyecto web frontend, te recomiendo elegir algun framework como JSP, (Java Server Pages), esto te ayudará a generar tus templates y manejarlos de una mejor manera.
Te comparto las siguientes ligas: Para generar el framework:
Springboot con JSP Para mejorar los templates yo solía usar Apache Tiles pero
veo que ya esta descontinuado, iugal puedes probar y aprender
Thymeleaf Thymeleaf Espero que la guía te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.
